# Korean Romanization to Hangeul library

Tags: javascript, strings, library, unicode, natural-language-processing

After a little work, I've finally ironed this out... Though could I get someone to go over this and see if there is a better way to present this library within the code, before I publish it?

**Premise:** Kimchi (a Korean transliteration library)

Kimchi, apart from being a delicious Korean side dish is also a Korean transliteration library that takes romanized input and transliterates (not translates) said text into the equivalent Hangeul character syllable blocks.

There are currently two commands, `kimchi.all()` and `kimchi.convert(str)`; `kimchi.convert(str)` will convert the `str` string variable into the corresponding Korean syllable blocks. `kimchi.all()` will go through the DOM and apply `kimchi.convert()` on the innerHTML component of each `<kimchi>` tag. Basically treat `<kimchi>` tags the same way as you would a `<span>` tag.

The library (save as `kimchi.js`):

```
var kimchi = {
    convert: function(fromText) {
        // Internal search function, avoids issues with non existent Array.indexOf() functionality in certain versions
        var inArr=function(a,s){for(var x=-1,y=0;y<a.length;y++)if(a[y]==s){x=y;break}return x};

        // Lower case the input text, build LVT arrays and init output text
        fromText = fromText.toLowerCase(),
        aLead = "g0kk0n0d0tt0r0m0b0pp0s0ss0-0j0jj0ch0k0t0p0h".split(0),
        aVowel = "a0ae0ya0yae0eo0e0yeo0ye0o0wa0wae0oe0yo0u0wo0we0wi0yu0eu0ui0i".split(0),
        aTail = "g0gg0gs0n0nj0nh0d0l0lg0lm0lb0ls0lt0lp0lh0m0b0bs0s0ss0ng0j0c0k0t0p0h".split(0),
        toText = "";

        // Split into Alpha/Dash and non-Alpha/Dash arrays
        // Then it's simply a matter of flipping between the two arrays and displaying accordingly.
        aKorean = fromText.split(/[^a-z\-]+/) || [],
            aNotKorean = fromText.split(/[a-z\-]+/) || [],
            iType = 3,
            iPhase = 0;
        // Loop through each Korean word.
        for (var iLoop = 0; iLoop < aKorean.length; iLoop++) {
            sWord = aKorean[iLoop];

            // Determine if first letter is vowel, if so latch a dash on its front.
            sWord = (~"aeiouwy".indexOf(sWord[0]) ? "-" : "") + sWord;

            // Loop through in reverse and extract letter blocks.
            for (var sLetterExt = "", bFoundLetter = !1, sLetterBlock = "", iLoop2 = sWord.length - 1; - 1 < iLoop2; iLoop2--)
                                for (var iLocationLast = iLoop2, iLen = 1; !bFoundLetter;) {
                                        // Attempt to find letter in chosen array
                                        // This is important, as there is no chance that a letter will be missed... 
                                        // At least I hope not...
                                    sExtract = sWord.substr(iLocationLast - iLen + 1, iLen);
                                    iLocation = inArr([aLead, aVowel, aTail][iType - 1], sExtract);
                                    if (0 > iLocation && "" == sLetterExt) {
                            // If the letter isn't found, move to next logical array,
                            // move cursor back and break out of current loop for restart.
                                        iType = 1 > iType - 1 ? 3 : iType - 1;
                                        iLoop2++;
                                        break
                                    }
                                    if (0 > iLocation && "" == sLetterExt && 1 == iPhase) {
                            // If the letter found is a - and the previous letter found is a lead,
                            // ignore it as this is plainly a divisionary - and not a mute.
                            // Move to tail array, move cursor forward and break out of 
                            // current loop for restart.
                                        iType = 3;
                                        break
                                    } else if (0 > iLocation && "" != sLetterExt && 0 == iLocationLast && 1 == iLen && 1 == iType) {
                        // It's gone as far as it can, and it can't go any further...
                        // Flag letter found and assign letter type, then relocate cursor.
                                        bLetterFound = !0;
                                        sLetterBlock = (1 == iType ? " " : "") + (1 < iType ? "/" : "") + sLetterExt + sLetterBlock;
                                        iLoop2 = iLocationLast - iLen + 1;
                                        sLetterExt = "";
                                        break
                                    } else if (0 > iLocation && "" != sLetterExt)
                            // It's gone as far as it can, and it can't go any further...
                            // Flag letter found and assign letter type, then relocate cursor.
                                            bLetterFound = !0, 
                                            iType == iPhase && "" != sLetterBlock && (sLetterBlock = " -" + sLetterBlock), 
                                            sLetterBlock = (1 == iType ? " " : "") + (1 < iType ? "/" : "") + sLetterExt + sLetterBlock, 
                                            iLoop2 = iLocationLast - iLen + 1, 
                                            sLetterExt = "", 
                                            iPhase = iType;
                                    else if (sLetterExt = sExtract, 0 == iLocationLast) {
                                        bLetterFound = !0;
                                        sLetterBlock = sExtract + sLetterBlock;
                                        iType = 3;
                                        break
                                    } else iLen++
                                }

                        sKoreanConv = "";
                        aConvKorean = sLetterBlock.split(" ");
                        // Determine the Unicode character value for the syllable block... 
                        for (var a = 0; a < aConvKorean.length; a++) 
                                "" != aConvKorean[a] && (aSyllable = aConvKorean[a].split("/"), sKoreanConv += "&#" + ((2 == aSyllable.length ? 0 : inArr(aTail, aSyllable[2]) + 1) + 28 * inArr(aVowel, aSyllable[1]) + 588 * inArr(aLead, aSyllable[0]) + 44032) + ";");
                        aKorean[iLoop] = sKoreanConv;
                        sKoreanConv = "";
        }
        bNotKoreanStart = aNotKorean ? 0 == fromText.indexOf(aNotKorean[0]) ? !0 : !1 : !1;
        iCounter = 0;
                if (bNotKoreanStart && aNotKorean.length == aKorean.length)
                    for (var iDisp = 0; iDisp < aNotKorean.length; iDisp++) toText += aNotKorean[iDisp] + aKorean[iDisp];
                else if (!bNotKoreanStart && aNotKorean.length == aKorean.length)
                    for (iDisp = 0; iDisp < aNotKorean.length; iDisp++) toText += aKorean[iDisp] + aNotKorean[iDisp];
                else if (bNotKoreanStart) {
                    if (toText += aNotKorean[0], 1 < aNotKorean.length)
                        for (iDisp = 0; iDisp < aKorean.length; iDisp++) toText += aKorean[iDisp] + aNotKorean[iDisp + 1]
                } else if (!bNotKoreanStart && (toText += aKorean[0], 1 < aKorean.length))
                    for (iDisp = 0; iDisp < aNotKorean.length; iDisp++) toText += aNotKorean[iDisp] + aKorean[iDisp + 1];
        return toText;
    },
    all: function() {
            // Affects all <kimchi> tags... 
        var z = document.getElementsByTagName('kimchi');
        for (x = z.length; x--;) {
            z[x].innerHTML = kimchi.convert(z[x].childNodes[0].data);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <script src="kimchi.js"></script>
    <body onLoad="kimchi.all();">
        <kimchi>hangug-eo, radio, seoul, pyeong-yang, kimchi</kimchi> - some random words in Korean<br/>
        <kimchi>Kim Yu Suk</kimchi>: the name of a genuine Korean Olympic high jumper<br />
        <span id="test"></span>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = kimchi.convert("pyeong-yang");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Readability

As a library author,
I think readability should be one of your top concerns.
This is hardly considered readable,
in fact it kinda breaks almost all known good practices of readable coding:

> ```
> var inArr=function(a,s){for(var x=-1,y=0;y<a.length;y++)if(a[y]==s){x=y;break}return x};
> ```

This would be magnitudes better:

```
function in_arr(arr, item) {
    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        if (arr[index] == item) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

#### Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

This is the warning given by [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) for this piece of code:

> ```
> fromText = fromText.toLowerCase(),
> aLead = "g0kk0n0d0tt0r0m0b0pp0s0ss0-0j0jj0ch0k0t0p0h".split(0),
> aVowel = "a0ae0ya0yae0eo0e0yeo0ye0o0wa0wae0oe0yo0u0wo0we0wi0yu0eu0ui0i".split(0),
> aTail = "g0gg0gs0n0nj0nh0d0l0lg0lm0lb0ls0lt0lp0lh0m0b0bs0s0ss0ng0j0c0k0t0p0h".split(0),
> toText = "";
> ```

This maybe subjective, but instead of `0` as the separator symbol,
I'd find space much much more readable.

Separating variable assignments with comma is used when declaring and assigning multiple variables in a single statement starting with the `var` keyword. 
To make this valid, you could terminate the re-assignment of `fromText`, and put `var` in front of `aLead`, like this:

```
fromText = fromText.toLowerCase();
var aLead = "g0kk0n0d0tt0r0m0b0pp0s0ss0-0j0jj0ch0k0t0p0h".split(0),
aVowel = "a0ae0ya0yae0eo0e0yeo0ye0o0wa0wae0oe0yo0u0wo0we0wi0yu0eu0ui0i".split(0),
aTail = "g0gg0gs0n0nj0nh0d0l0lg0lm0lb0ls0lt0lp0lh0m0b0bs0s0ss0ng0j0c0k0t0p0h".split(0),
toText = "";
```

In case you're wondering, you couldn't simply put `var` in front of `fromText`, because the variable is already defined.

#### Unexpected use of '~'

Another warning by [JSHint](http://jshint.com/), for this bit:

> ```
> sWord = (~"aeiouwy".indexOf(sWord[0]) ? "-" : "") + sWord;
> ```

This is too clever. Clever code is not a virtue.
It makes code harder to read.
You could rewrite it less clever and without warnings:

```
sWord = ("aeiouwy".indexOf(sWord[0]) >= 0 ? "-" : "") + sWord;
```

#### More 'clever' code

What's up with statements like this:

> ```
> bFoundLetter = !1
> ```

Why make things simple complicated?
You really should focus on making things as simple as possible:

```
bFoundLetter = false;
```

Another thing, the Hungarian notation is frowned upon.
Just call it `foundLetter`, simple, natural.

#### More warnings on JSHint

There are many many other warnings pointed out by JSHint,
I suggest to copy-paste your code,
review all reported violations,
and try to fix them all.

#### Strange indentation

The second `for` statement here has crazy excessive indentation:

> ```
> for (var sLetterExt = "", bFoundLetter = !1, sLetterBlock = "", iLoop2 = sWord.length - 1; - 1 < iLoop2; iLoop2--)
>                     for (var iLocationLast = iLoop2, iLen = 1; !bFoundLetter;) {
> ```

Since the outer `for` statement is already quite deeply indented,
this really forces the reader to scroll horizontally,
which really seriously hurts readability.
And it's completely unnecessary,
you could just indent by 4 spaces like you do in most of the rest of the code.

#### Use braces always

A lot of `for` loops and `if` conditions don't use braces around their statement, for example:

> ```
> if (bNotKoreanStart && aNotKorean.length == aKorean.length)
>     for (var iDisp = 0; iDisp < aNotKorean.length; iDisp++) toText += aNotKorean[iDisp] + aKorean[iDisp];
> else if (!bNotKoreanStart && aNotKorean.length == aKorean.length)
>     for (iDisp = 0; iDisp < aNotKorean.length; iDisp++) toText += aKorean[iDisp] + aNotKorean[iDisp];
> ```

This goes against the common recommendation to always use braces.
Especially in code that's already very hard to read,
it's very important to diligently put those braces:

```
if (bNotKoreanStart && aNotKorean.length == aKorean.length) {
    for (var iDisp = 0; iDisp < aNotKorean.length; iDisp++) {
        toText += aNotKorean[iDisp] + aKorean[iDisp];
    }
} else if (!bNotKoreanStart && aNotKorean.length == aKorean.length) {
    for (iDisp = 0; iDisp < aNotKorean.length; iDisp++) {
        toText += aKorean[iDisp] + aNotKorean[iDisp];
    }
}
```

Not using braces always can cause grave problems [like this famous bug](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html).

#### Conclusion

The things I pointed out above are but a few examples of problems that appear in many places of the code.
I suggest to:

- Apply the above suggestions to all similar patterns in the code
- Replace all "clever" tricks with simple their corresponding simple intuitive alternatives (`!0` is really `true`, and `!1` is really `false`)
- Format the code nicely, make it as easy to read as possible
- Go over all JSHint warnings and make your code as spotless as possible

Comment: Thank you! This is the kind of information I needed, and not down votes without comment... I believe I may have a simplified version somewhere. I'll replace the above with it shortly.

Comment: Don't change the code in your post though. [See this relevant meta post.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765) Btw there are no downvotes on your question now

Comment: Ah yes, the "selfie answer" I think they called it... I'll do it that way...